# Why I can't get the advanced soldier rig?

Tags: dead-space

I loaded a cleared game save and after finally reaching the store at the end of chapter 1 the rig isn't available

I thought all you had to do was complete the game and then pay 99,000 credits for it, why it isn't in the store then?

Comment: Good question. [This Dead Space wiki article agrees that that's all you should have to do.](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Soldier_RIG)

Answer (score 1):

When you load a cleared game, you receive a "Level 6 Schematic" in your inventory. Bring this to the Store, and you will be able to purchase the suit.

I don't remember exactly, since it has been quite a while since I played, but I believe that if your inventory is full when you load the game, you won't be able to receive it. It might be dropped at your feet, but that's just speculation.